# Vue.js Select specific value

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I have these lines in my HTML:

```
<v-select v-model="user2_id" :options="[{!! $users !!}]" class="select">
</v-select>
<input type="hidden" v-model="user2_id" name="user2_id">
```

I have defined the $users variable like this:

```
<?php
    $lusers = '';

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        if($user->id !== Auth::user()->id)
            $lusers .= '{label: \'' . $user->name . '\', value: ' . $user->id . '},';
    }
    $users = trim($lusers, ',');
?>
```

These generates the following line:

`:options="[{label: 'user 1', value: 1},{label: 'User 2', value: 2}]"`

And the data is shown successfully.

When I submit the form I get this: `"user2_id" => "[object Object]"`. I need to get `user2_id => 2` (i.e.). Which is the proper way to have this done?
I've tried to use `v-model="user2_id.value"` but is not working.

The [original documentation](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) is not helping.

Thanks

Comment: What do you get after `print_r($user)`?

Comment: the users are rendered successfully. A $user is an object

Comment: You should use `:value.sync` option for Two-Way Value Syncing

Comment: How I accomplish this? Where should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `v-select` is clever enough to look for a `label` member to use for display, it continues to use the whole object as the value.

Since your hidden input is not interactive, you don't need the two-way binding of `v-model`. Just use `:value=user2_id.value` instead. In my snippet, I make it a text input so you can see what's going on.

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user2_id: null
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/sagalbot/vue-select/master/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-select v-model="user2_id" :options="[{label: 'user 1', value: 1},{label: 'User 2', value: 2}]" class="select">
  </v-select>
  <input type="text" :value="user2_id && user2_id.value" name="user2_id">
  <div>{{JSON.stringify(user2_id)}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
<v-select v-model="user2_id" :options="[!! $users !!]" class="select">
</v-select>
```

Comment: You are not getting the question, the information is well displayed. The issue is after I submit the form.